# Fine Uploader Concurrent Chunking - Endpoint

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

When concurrent chunking is enabled the app sends a final POST request to an endpoint of your choice to let you know that the upload is complete.  I would like to use my same endpoint for all of the requests (not just the final concurrent chunking POST), but I don't see anything really unique about the POST.  For example, in the documentation is says the following:

> Fine Uploader will also include the following parameters that describe the underlying file:
>
> qquuid: the UUID of the underlying file.
>   qqfilename: the name of the underlying file.
>   qqtotalfilesize: the size, in bytes, of the underlying file.
>   qqtotalparts: the total number of parts that make up the underlying file.

But all of those items are standard values sent with the other POST requests.  Is there anything unique about the final POST that I can catch in an an if/then type of statement?  Right now I have it working based off of whether it is a multipart POST or not.  If it is, it should contain file data, and if it isn't it should be the final message.  Is there another indicator that I could check on it instead?  Like something specifically saying "concurrent chunking complete?"

It's working for me as it is, but it just seems pretty hacky to do it the way I am doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like the "all chunks done" POST to be sent to the same endpoint, but require an easy way to tell that request from the upload requests, simply include a query parameter at the end of the URL.

For example:

```
request: {
    endpoint: "/my/uploads"
},
chunking: {
    enabled: true,
    success: {
        endpoint: "/my/uploads?done"
    }
}
```

Now, you can tell if the POST refers to a chunking.success POST, or not, simply by looking for the presence of a "done" parameter in the request URI server-side.